# Trying to use `pwd` inside an alias giving unexpected results

Tags: alias, search, file-search

If I want to search a file in the system I use the following command:

```
sudo find `pwd` -name filename.ext
```

I want to make an alias for an easier word like `search`, so I used the command:

```
alias search "find `pwd` -name "
```

The problem is that the command translates the `pwd` part to the actual path i'm in now. When i type simply `alias` to see the list of aliases I see:

```
search   find /path/to/my/homedir -name
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: which shell are you using?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use single quotes to avoid shell expansion at time of definition

```
alias search='find `pwd` -name '
```

Comment: Note that it's POSIX `sh` syntax, not `csh` syntax. In POSIX `sh`, the output of `pwd` would undergo split+glob which you don't want here, you'd need `find "$(pwd)"` or better still `find "$PWD"`. In `csh`, quoting (as in `find "\`pwd\`"`) helps a little in that it disables globbing but the output of `pwd` is still split (though this time into the non-empty lines in `pwd`'s output instead of the (space, tab and newline searated)  _words_.

Answer (score 4):

Modify the command as:

```
alias search="find . -name "
```

So it will always *search* in current directory only i.e. Present Working Directory

Comment: Yes, but it will report file paths as `./foo/file.txt`, as opposed to `/current/dir/foo/file.txt`. Also, that's POSIX sh syntax, not csh syntax like in the OP's question.

Answer (score 4):

command substitution is expanded inside double quotes in (t)csh (that you seem to be using) like in Bourne-like shells.

So in:

```
alias search "find `pwd` -name "
```

You're actually doing something like:

```
alias search 'find /some/dir -name '
```

Where `/some/dir` was the current directory at the time that `alias` command was run.

Here, you want:

```
alias search 'find $cwd:q -name'
```

`$cwd` is automatically set by `tcsh` (so is `$PWD` in modern versions, like in POSIX shells), so you can use it in place of the less efficient and less reliable `` `pwd` ``.

We use single (strong) quotes so that that `$cwd` is not expanded within.

`$cwd:q` is to pass the value of the variable as one argument as opposed to let it undergo splitting.

Also note that you don't need the space after `-name` above.

If you wanted to use `pwd` (for instance so that you get the canonical (symlink-free) path to the current working directory as in some `pwd` implementations like the GNU one when `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is not in the environment), you'd use:

```
alias search 'find "`pwd`" -name'
```

Though that wouldn't work if the path of the current directory contains newline characters.

Note that you can't use `sudo search` as aliases are only expanded in command position in (t)csh. In POSIX shells you could do:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

To tell the shell that the word following `sudo` should also undergo alias expansion, but that trick doesn't work in (t)csh.

The POSIX `sh` (or `bash`/`zsh`/`ksh`...) equivalent would be:

```
alias search='find "$PWD" -name'
```

Answer (score 0):

`alias` is evluated once is called. There is no option to call command when callnig alias. You have to write a bash function, where you can run sub commands or, better, use `.`  (search in current dir) instead of `pwd`.

Comment: `alias is evluated once is called. There is no option to call command when callnig alias.` But of course there is, if the alias contains an expression that evaluates to a command, as long as the OP uses the right quotes to ensure evaluation happens at the right time: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303675/124753